# Meaning of struct pid_type in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux

I see that a `linux\pid.h` in the kernel defines the following type:

```
enum pid_type
{
    PIDTYPE_PID,
    PIDTYPE_TGID,
    PIDTYPE_PGID,
    PIDTYPE_SID,
    PIDTYPE_MAX,
};
```

and the `struct pid` type uses it when keeping track of the tasks associated to the PID:

```
struct pid
{
    atomic_t count;
    unsigned int level;
    /* lists of tasks that use this pid */
    struct hlist_head tasks[PIDTYPE_MAX];
    struct rcu_head rcu;
    struct upid numbers[1];
};
```

But what does each list refers to? It's my understanding that `PIDTYPE_PID` refers to tasks which use this as PID (the "thread ID" from kernel perspective) and `PIDTYPE_TGID` as tasks which use this as TGID, i.e. thread group ID which denotes a group of threads which share the same userspace PID, what are `PIDTYPE_PGID` and `PIDTYPE_SID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SID = session ID, 
PGID = process group ID  as described here:
https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html